# Nullpointerexception - while Passing data via intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am having an issue where I can not sort out the `NullPointerException` (NPE) that I am getting.

Here is my MainActivity code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String bccode = result.getContents();

        if(result != null) {
            if(result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent sendBarCode= new Intent(MainActivity.this, showdata.class);
                sendBarCode.putExtra("barccode", bccode);
                startActivity(sendBarCode);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, showdata.class));
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
 }
```

And my class that receives it showdata.class:

```
public String barcode = getIntent().getStringExtra("barccode");
```

The exact error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This particular NPE has me a bit perplexed as I have followed all the instructions I can find online.

Comment: while it's good to have the checks as some of the answers suggest, your issue is that you're calling `startActivity` twice and because of that, the `intent` is null in your receiving class.

Comment: Ohh... That makes total sense! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're calling `startActivity` twice, once with the data and once with a new `Intent` which will not have any data..

Comment: Thanks Synex, I did not realize that was an issue

Answer (score 2):

Protect from NPE

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
   ...
}
else {
    Log.d(TAG, "No intent");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TRY This out in the `showdata` class.**

```
public String barcode = null;
Intent i = getIntent();
barcode =i.getStringExtra("barccode");
```